# How to store CHAR array to string MAC ADDRESS

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a function that returns a `unsigned char chMAC[6];` which is the mac address and i print it out as

```
printf("Mac: %x",chMAC[0]);
printf("%x",chMAC[1]);
printf("%x",chMAC[2]);
printf("%x",chMAC[3]);
printf("%x",chMAC[4]);
printf("%x\n",chMAC[5]);
```

And i get an output as `Mac: B827E82D398E` which is the actual mac address, but now i need to get that value as a string to pass to a sql parameter and i don't know how, since i need to add `:` in between. such as `Mac: B8:27:E8:2D:39:8E`

i bet this is easy, but i am still learning  C.

Comment: Look at `sprintf()`, or better yet, `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want all the bytes to be displayed as two characters:

```
%2x
```

but with a leading 0 instead of space:

```
%02x
```

You can string this all together in one `printf` call

```
printf("Mac: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n"
       , chMAC[0], chMAC[1], chMAC[2], chMAC[3], chMAC[4], chMAC[5]);
```

If you want the text to go to a sting buffer instead of `stdout` do this:

```
char buffer[32];

snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)
        , "Mac: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n"
        , chMAC[0], chMAC[1], chMAC[2], chMAC[3], chMAC[4], chMAC[5]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have all the pieces there, you just need to string them into the right order.  Instead of using 6 separate printf() statements, pull it into one statement with all the formatting:

```
printf("Mac: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n", 
             chMAC[0], chMAC[1], chMAC[2], chMAC[3], chMAC[4], chMAC[5]);
```

The "02" in the "%02X" formatting statements will put a leading zero if the value is <15; the capital X will make the alphabetic Hex digits into capitals (which is the usual convention when passing MAC addresses).

To send the resulting string to a buffer instead of to stdout, call sprintf (or even better, snprintf) with the same formatting string.

```
char mac_str[24];
snprintf(mac_str, sizeof(mac_str), "Mac: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n", 
              chMAC[0], chMAC[1], chMAC[2], chMAC[3], chMAC[4], chMAC[5]);
```

Comment: He asked how to store it in a string, not how to print it.

Answer (score 0):

why all the separate calls?

```
newlength = sprintf(mac, '%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n', chMAC[1], etc....)
```

You can have multiple `%whatever` format characters in a single printf/sprintf call...

Comment: i read the documentation on sprintf but it retunres the number of displayed chars, `If successful, the total number of characters written is returned excluding the null-character appended at the end of the string, otherwise a negative number is returned in case of failure.`

Comment: You're missing the output buffer argument.

Comment: yeah, sorry.  been buried in php-land too long. fixing up the sample.